# Is there any way to match the whole word on Hunspell affix condition?

Tags: libreoffice, hunspell

I'm using Hunspell as a spell checker and I'm facing a problem.

I have written the following line

```
SFX A a o [^abc]bla
```

hoping that it will match the word "bla", but it is not so. It matches "xbla", "ybla", etc.

How can I make it matches only "bla" as a whole word without any "prefix"? (that is without matching "xbla", but only "bla")

I use LibreOffice 5.1.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to work around the problem. I defined a rule for each special word and tagged them in the dictionary.

```
SFX A a o [^abc]bla

SFX B a o bla
```

While in the dictionary:

```
xbla/A
...
bla/B
```